# Displaying ASP Code inside DIV (inline)

Tags: css, asp-classic

I'm setting up a 'shopping cart' on our website, the ASP code is causing me some headaches can anyone offer some advice:

Note in the image below, when items are added to the cart the 'total' is displayed on the second line. I would like everything to appear on the same line, what is wrong in my code causing this issue?

[image]

You can visit the page at:
http://www.heatx.org/productcart/pc/viewCategories.asp?idCategory=2
then add the (1) item listed to your cart...
and notice the total gets moved to the second line...

thanks...

Comment: Which browser has the problem?

Comment: you will have to Show the code

Comment: This is some CSS issue, not related to classic ASP.

Comment: "You can visit the page at: http://www.heatx.org/productcart/pc/viewCategories.asp?idCategory=2 then add the (1) item listed to your cart" - or, alternatively, you could copy and paste the relevant code into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two CSS issues causing the text to break to a new line

```
#pcIconBarLeft a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #06F;
   /*float: left;*/
}
#pcIconBar a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #666;
   /*float: left;*/
}
```

Notice the `float:left;` for both of those. If you take those out the Total text will be on the same line.